# Check if value is available in 3 arrays

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working on a postcode checker, on if a user enters in their postcode, the function checks 3 arrays:

- if the customer postcode begins with 4 letters/numbers, it checks array 1
- if customer postcode begins with 3 letters/numbers, it checks array 2
- if customer postcode begins with 2 letters/numbers, it checks array 3

This function also converts the users input to a uppercase as all the array values are uppercase.

**Problem:** The function worked with 2 arrays being checked with an elseif command. However, when i introduced 3 arrays, it has stopped working. Does anyone know on what i did wrong? please refer to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24Mqw/6/ for the full code

```
var postcodemain = ['TR21', 'TR22', 'TR23', 'TR24', 'TR25', 'PO30', 'PO31', 'PO32', 'PO33', 'PO34', 'PO35', 'PO36', 'PO37', 'PO38', 'PO39', 'PO40', 'PO41', 'AB30', 'AB31', 'AB33', 'AB34', 'AB35', 'AB36', 'AB37'];

var postcodesecond = ['IM1', 'IM2', 'IM3', 'IM4', 'IM5', 'IM6', 'IM7', 'IM8', 'IM9', 'G83', 'IV1', 'IV2', 'IV3', 'IV4', 'IV5', 'IV6', 'IV7', 'IV8', 'IV9', 'KW1', 'KW2', 'KW3', 'KW5', 'KW6', 'KW7', 'KW8', 'KW9', 'HS1', 'HS2', 'HS3', 'HS4', 'HS5', 'HS6', 'HS7', 'HS8', 'HS9', 'ZE1', 'ZE2', 'ZE3'];

var postcodethird = ['BT', 'GY', 'JE'];

var mainfirst = $(this).val().toUpperCase().substring(0, 3);
var mainsecond = $(this).val().toUpperCase().substring(0, 2);
var mainthird = $(this).val().toUpperCase().substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: Yup, slicing off one too many characters -> http://jsfiddle.net/24Mqw/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) excludes the end position

```
    var value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var mainfirst = value.substring(0, 4);
    var mainsecond = value.substring(0, 3);
    var mainthird = value.substring(0, 2);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sAVW3/)